# If int is a value type and object is reference type as object is base class for int then why so?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value Type Vs Reference Type - Object Class C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205444/value-type-vs-reference-type-object-class-c-sharp)
>   [Why is Int32 a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753542/why-is-int32-a-value-type)

Everyone knows that object is the base class for any type.
But why int is value type? It should be a reference type.

Comment: The low-level `object` itself is neither a reference, nor a value type. Does that answer your question?

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205444/value-type-vs-reference-type-object-class-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

[Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), not a class. So it's a value type.

For more information: [go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=vs.80%29).

Comment: But struct don't inherit from object or do they?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Everything inherits from `object`. Otherwise, how did you think that stuff like `123.ToString()` was implemented?

Comment: @MrLister: You will also find .ToString() in interfaces in .NET, yet interfaces don't inherit from System.Object. (I agree with your conclusion, just not with the proof you give.)

Comment: @MrLister: My point is that the fact that `.ToString()` is available is only because of a special exception in the compiler that adds object's members even for some types that don't actually inherit from object.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal So maybe that was not too good an example. But [the page I linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx) says literally: "In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object. You can assign values of any type to variables of type object." I can't make it any more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Int is a struct - a value type is defined like this:

```
public struct MyValueType
{
}
```

a reference type is defined like this

```
public class MyReferenceType
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int is not ant Object it is a Primitive data type in C# it is called struct  .Corresponding Object for an int is Integer.Object class is parent class of all reference type.

Comment: `int` is an object. Everything derives from `object`.

Comment: @MrLister : May be in c# i am wrong but In java int is primitive data type not an object ,corresponding class is Integer.

Comment: But we're not talking about Java or any other language but C#.

Answer (score 0):

Object is the base `class` for any other class. int is not a class, its a struct, what you are maybe talking about is [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx)

Comment: No, this is not true. `int` (and everything else) is definitely inherited from `object`. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx)

Comment: @MrLister ive read maybe a good dozen of explanatins on this, and it honestly sounds like microsofts engineers cannto decide among themselves what is what. you are right in what youre saying, but theres also a difference between treating a ref type as object and value type as such (boxing/unboxing)