# What is System.Object ??? Reference type or Value Type

Tags: c#

As per my bookish knowledge I have learnt that System.object is reference type.
I have tried following things to get understanding of the same:
1. I had written following code in main method:

```
Object KC = 12;
Get data(12); // method where I'm passing variable kj.
//I'm performing some manipulation in method for kj & value sets as 15. 
Console.WriteLine(kj); // Expected output is 15 .
```

Considering kj is object and reference type. But I'm getting output as 12.......

Can someone explain me the above situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Int32 a value type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753542/why-is-int32-a-value-type)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: @MeirionHughes That has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 1):

Reference-types are not passed by reference *by default* in C#. They're passed by value, even for reference type. However, the value of a *reference* type can be visualized as simply a pointer.

What you're actually passing is a copy of the pointer. Any modification to that copy does *not* change the original reference.

```
void Main()
{
    Object kj = 12;

    GetData(kj); 
    Console.WriteLine(kj); //Prints 12
}

void GetData(Object o)
{
    //At this point, o is a pointer to the object 'kj'
    o = 15;

    //Now o is a pointer to a _new_ object which boxes the value 15.
}
```

To get the functionality you're after, you'll need to explicitly pass it by reference:

```
void Main()
{
    Object kj = 12;

    GetData(ref kj); 
    Console.WriteLine(kj); //Prints 15
}

void GetData(ref Object o)
{
    o = 15;
}
```

Now we're actually passing by reference, so any change to `o` *does* affect the original reference.